# Doctrine 2 ORM and WordPress - Centralizing Doctrine management for multiple dependent applications

Tags: php, wordpress, doctrine-orm, entities, entitymanager

In WordPress, plugins are created and distributed as packages for other WordPress users to install.

Each of the plugins I'm creating share certain common entities in a core plugin. I'm struggling with creating and managing the `EntitiyManager` to use among these plugins.

I've come up with two ways to implement this and would like to hear some feedback before moving forward:

**Option 1:** Single, global EntityManager

```
// Example Plugin
    // Unique Entities
    // Add Unique Entity Paths and REQUIRED Entity Paths from Core Entities to EntityManager

// Example Plugin
    // Unique Entities
    // Add Unique Entity Paths and REQUIRED Entity Paths from Core Entities to EntityManager

// Core Plugin
    // Core Entities
    // Contains EntityManager
```

The problem with this version is that, although there is a way to add paths to a `MetadataDriver`:

`$entityManager->getConfig()->getMetadataDriverImpl()->addPaths();`

I am not sure if this will actually update the `MetadataDriver` within the `config` of this `EntityManager`. My worries is that this will only return a `config` that has been updated with the new paths and not update the `EntityManager`'s config.

Is this true?

Note that there is no `setConfig` function so if it is, I would have to recreate the `EntityManager` from each plugin, defeating the purpose of a centralized `EntityManager`.

**Option 2:** Multiple EntityManagers

```
// Example Plugin
    // Unique Entities
    // Create EntityManager with Unique Entity path and path to Core Entities that are required for this plugin.

// Core Plugin
    // Core Entities
```

The problem with this implementation is that it seems inefficient. I've noticed that there is a Doctrine plugin for WordPress, although it is Doctrine 1.2.3, and it allows you to have one centralized place as I would assume is appropriate for managing applications that share resources like the *Core Entities*.

What are your thoughts on using Doctrine in this scenario. Is there a way to centralize the operations so that the ORM is managed through one central plugin that others depend upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out that:

```
$entityManager->getConfiguration()->getMetadataDriverImpl()->addPaths();
```

Does in fact add additional paths to the `$entityManager` object and not just to the config that is returned with `getConfiguration`.

I will continue finishing up this implementation and update with my results here. Hopefully the core can become distributable as a plugin for other programmers to use.